# How to select sunday before first monday of the passed month

Tags: java, date

I want to select `Sunday` **before** first `Monday` of the passed month.

That `Sunday` may be in the same month or the previous month but I want date of `Sunday`. I tried below logic for getting `Sunday`, it works for the current month but if I try passing some another month like `Nov-2017` then again I have to change `MONDAY-2` to `MONDAY-3`. So this is not the correct way. So how can I achieve this ?

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.println("Date " + c.getTime());
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.MONDAY - 2);
System.out.println("Date " + c.getTime());
```

I want to pass date to the code. So how can i do it ? like if I have date saved in variable then according to the input provided by that variable it should calculate the logic and provide the output

Comment: I have updated my question. Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: First, don’t use the long outdated `Calendar`class. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is not only generally much nicer to work with, it is also better suited for tasks like yours.

Comment: Okay so how can i do that ? can you provide me some code where i can pass some variable as date ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48417024/5772882) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48416944/5772882).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “pass some variable as date”? Maybe you should update your question again and specify exactly what you have got (type and example value) and what you require (with type if you require a certain type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Test
public void testDate() throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    Date d = fmt.parse("01-Nov-2017");
    System.out.println(d);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    getSundayBefore1thMondayOfMonth(c);
}

public void getSundayBefore1thMondayOfMonth(Calendar c) {
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    int wd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (wd > Calendar.MONDAY ) {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
    }
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
}



Wed Nov 01 00:00:00 CST 2017
Mon Nov 06 00:00:00 CST 2017
Sun Nov 05 00:00:00 CST 2017
```

Comment: Looks pretty simple. I ll accept this one . Thanks @yudong

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar, there is a bug here, fixed just now

Comment: After your edit the result is `Sun Jan 07 09:13:30 CET 2018`, which is not correct according to _That `Sunday` may be in the same month or the previous month_.

Comment: Code works perfectly for the current month but suppose i want to input month as dec-2017 and then have to calculate logic accordingly then where should i make change in the above code @yudongshen

Comment: Where can i pass my variable ?

Comment: I have updated my question . Can you please help me ?

Comment: Thank you so much i ll try and ll let u know :)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). So much simpler, just a one-liner: `YearMonth.now().atDay( 1 ).with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ).minusDays( 1 )`

Comment: Nice basil i ll try that one as well . BTW @yudongshen your code works like a charm !

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8, Then you can use [**java.time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library and you can just use :

```
LocalDate firstMondayOfMonth = LocalDate.now().with(
        TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
);// This return 2018-01-01

LocalDate sunday = firstMondayOfMonth.minusDays(1);//This return 2017-12-31
```

---

To test with November 2017 you can use `LocalDate.of` instead `LocalDate.now()` like this :

```
LocalDate firstMondayOfMonth = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.NOVEMBER, 1).with(
        TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
);// This return 2017-11-06

LocalDate firstSunday = firstMondayOfMonth.minusDays(1);// This return 2017-11-05
```

Comment: how to pass variable instead of Month.NOVEMEBER in your code . can i do it so ? if not then how can i do using your code

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar `Month.NOVEMEBER` comes from an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html), you can use  `Month.NOVEMEBER` or `11` (`LocalDate.of(2017, 11, 1)`) instead, take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int- is that what you mean ?

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar `Month` is an enum. An enum carries one or more predefined objects, objects that are automatically instantiated when the class loads. On `Month` we have a dozen such objects, each given a name: JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, etc. Each of those is a `static final public` class constant. You can use and pass these objects anywhere in your code. `someMethod( Month.AUGUST )`

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque for that explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth
    .now()          // Current year-month. Tip: Better to pass the optional time zone, as shown further down in this Answer.
    .atDay( 1 )     // First of the current month.
    .with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )  // Move from first day of month to the following Monday, or stay on the first if it already a Monday. 
    .minusDays( 1 ) // Move back one day from Monday to get a Sunday. May be in current month or in previous month.
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-date classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Determining the current month means determining the current date. Determining the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) ;
```

The `YearMonth` class represent the entire month.

```
YearMonth currentYearMonth = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
```

From that we can get the first of the month.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = currentYearMonth.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

We can move to a certain day of the week by calling on a `TemporalAdjuster`.

```
LocalDate firstMondayOfMonth = firstOfMonth.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
LocalDate sundayBeforeFirstMondayOfMonth = firstMondayOfMonth.with( TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ) ;
```

Logically, that last line could be replaced with `.minusDays( 1 )` as we know the previous Sunday immediately precedes our Monday by definition.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, first we get the first monday in the month. Then we just subtract 1 day.

```
    // input
    int year = 2017;
    int month = Calendar.NOVEMBER;

    // get first monday of the month
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    System.out.println("Date " + c.getTime());

    // subtract 1
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    System.out.println("Date " + c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setFirstDayOfWeek( Calendar.MONDAY); //Monday is first day of a week
c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek( 1); //first week of month is the week that has at least one day in this month
//c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek( 7); //first week of month must be a full week
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1); //move to first week of month
System.out.println("Date " + c.getTime());
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); //move to Monday
System.out.println("Date " + c.getTime());
c.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1); //go back one day
System.out.println("Date " + c.getTime());
```

Choose one of the `c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` method depending on what the *first week of month* means to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you can use the below code:

```
public static void getSundayBeforeFirstMondayOfMonth(LocalDate date){
    date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)).minusDays(1);
  }
```

And, call the above method like below as per the requirement:

```
public static void callerMethod(){
    // Call with Current Date
    getSundayBeforeFirstMondayOfMonth(LocalDate.now());

    //Call with Custom Date
    LocalDate customDate = LocalDate.parse("27-11-2017", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DD-MM-YYYY"));
    getSundayBeforeFirstMondayOfMonth(customDate);
  }
```